# Lead - Lithium = Gold?

Tags: nuclear-physics

In reference to [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21352/what-would-the-economic-impact-of-the-ability-to-transmute-lead-into-gold) about transmuting lead into gold, I'm looking for a correct, though magical, way to turn lead into gold.  I'm not worried if it's possible to split off a lithium nucleus from a lead nucleus to get gold (I know it isn't), I just want to know if my nuclear math is correct.

If you extract a lithium nucleus from lead is gold the result?

---

I realize this is a very naive question and it ignores a great deal about nuclear fusion, fission and isotopes.

Comment: No, you won't get a gold atom, you will get a gold ion with three extra electrons. Your magical way will need to get rid of them as well.

Comment: You don't need magic in order to move electrons around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to use lead-204, which has a natural abundance of 1.4%. If you want to use one of the more common isotopes of lead, you'll have a few extra neutrons. You could let them fly off and then decay into hydrogen.

Comment: Decay into hydrogen is acceptable.  What if we used Lead 208?  What would I need to subtract to get gold?

Comment: You'd need to subtract lithium-11. The heaviest stable isotope of lithium is lithium-7. I don't know how lithium-11 will decay, just that it will.

Comment: Wikipedia says Li-11 does beta decay to Be-11. Works for me.

Comment: No matter which isotope, Pb minus Li equals gold.

Comment: Yes. The problem is that if it's not gold-197, it will be highly radioactive.